# Get max and min value from array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, position

I am creating the following array from data attributes and I need to be able to grab the highest and lowest value from it so I can pass it to another function later on.

```
var allProducts = $(products).children("li");
prices = []
$(allProducts).each(function () {
    var price = parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
    prices[price] = price;
});
console.log(prices[0]) <!-- this returns undefined
```

My list items look like this (I have cut down for readability):

```
<li data-price="29.97"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
<li data-price="31.00"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
<li data-price="19.38"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
<li data-price="20.00"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
```

A quick console.log on prices shows me my array which appears to be sorted so I could grab the first and last element I assume, but presently the names and values in the array are the same so whenever I try and do a prices[0], I get *undefined*

```
[]
19.38   19.38
20.00   20.00
29.97   29.97
31.00   31.00
```

Got a feeling this is a stupidly easy question, so please be kind :)

Comment: Shouldn't this `prices[price]` be this: `prices.push()` in order to use the keys [0],[1]...?

Comment: How many prices are you likely to have?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

To get min/max value in array, you can use:

```
var _array = [1,3,2];
Math.max.apply(Math,_array); // 3
Math.min.apply(Math,_array); // 1
```

Comment: I used `Math.max.apply(null,_array)` and it worked fine. Any reason not to do it that way?

Comment: @ButtleButkus you can use `null` without any problem for the current case.

Mozilla guys also use it as first param in [their examples at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions):
`Math.max.apply(null, numbers);`

Comment: From ES6, you can use spreading of array:
```Math.max(...array);```

Answer (score 12):

Why not store it as an array of prices instead of object?

```
prices = []
$(allProducts).each(function () {
    var price = parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
    prices.push(price);
});
prices.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b }); //this is the magic line which sort the array
```

That way you can just

```
prices[0]; // cheapest
prices[prices.length - 1]; // most expensive
```

Note that you can do `shift()` and `pop()` to get min and max price respectively, but it will take off the price from the array.

Even better alternative is to use Sergei solution below, by using `Math.max` and `min` respectively.

EDIT:

I realized that this would be wrong if you have something like `[11.5, 3.1, 3.5, 3.7]` as `11.5` is treated as a string, and would come **before** the `3.x` in dictionary order, you need to pass in custom sort function to make sure they are indeed treated as float:

```
prices.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b });
```

Comment: surely you have to order the list somewhere to assume the first is cheapest and last is most expensive?

Comment: +1 for clear solution. at first i couldn't find `sort()` in your answer. so made comment near code

Comment: Your edit makes no sense, you're using `parseFloat` before adding to the array, so sort would automatically use numeric sorting rather than string.

Comment: @Jamiec did you test your comment? http://jsfiddle.net/9H2xg/1/. Or did I miss something here? :( I was also assuming the same way as you did

Comment: @Jamiec here's all the test, please tell me if I got it wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/9H2xg/10/

Comment: @SiGanteng - Magic. Thanks fellers, much appreciated.

Comment: No, you're absolutely right, my mistake. Totally weird though and not how i'd intuatively thought it would work.

Comment: I almost entirely agree with this, but I did a quick [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/max-min-vs-sort) test, and for arrays with length of more than 10 values, it is a bunch quicker to use `Math.max.apply(Math, arr)` and `Math.min.apply(Math, arr)` respectively than to actually sort the whole array? Any bigger than that and `max` or `min` win by a long way. And personally I think it's clearer as to what is happening.

Comment: Just a note: the sort function has an extra '}' at the end which needs to be replaced with a ')'.

Comment: Sorting the whole array in worst case will be `n*n - n` more expensive than a regular search of a min or max value.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of .each, another (perhaps more concise) approach to getting all those prices might be:

```
var prices = $(products).children("li").map(function() {
    return $(this).prop("data-price");
}).get();
```

additionally you may want to consider filtering the array to get rid of empty or non-numeric array values in case they should exist:

```
prices = prices.filter(function(n){ return(!isNaN(parseFloat(n))) });
```

then use Sergey's solution above:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math,prices);
var min = Math.min.apply(Math,prices);
```

Comment: The most elegant solution,imho

Comment: The recommended way. "The .map() method is particularly useful for getting or setting the value of a collection of elements." https://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = [9,4,2,93,6,2,4,61,1];
ArrMax = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
```

Comment: can you explain the answer?

Answer (score 3):

if you have "scattered" (not inside an array) values you can use:

```
var max_value = Math.max(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this and it works on both the static arrays and dynamically generated arrays.

```
var array = [12,2,23,324,23,123,4,23,132,23];
var getMaxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, array );
```

I had the issue when I use trying to find max value from code below

```
$('#myTabs').find('li.active').prevAll().andSelf().each(function () {
            newGetWidthOfEachTab.push(parseInt($(this).outerWidth()));
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < newGetWidthOfEachTab.length; i++) {
            newWidthOfEachTabTotal += newGetWidthOfEachTab[i];
            newGetWidthOfEachTabArr.push(parseInt(newWidthOfEachTabTotal));
        }

        getMaxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, array);
```

I was getting `'NAN'` when I use

```
    var max_value = Math.max(12, 21, 23, 2323, 23);
```

with my code

Answer (score 1):

Find largest and smallest number in an array with **[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#over)**.

```js
var array = [1, 3, 2];
var func = _.over(Math.max, Math.min);
var [max, min] = func(...array);
// => [3, 1]
console.log(max);
console.log(min);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: For modern javascript code this approach speaks volumes of elegance.

Answer (score 0):

If there exists requirement to find solution without using Math library, or Sorting logic, the below solutions might help.

To find the max value in javascript,

```
var max = -Infinity;
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] < max) continue;
    if (arr[i] > max) {
        max = arr[i];
 }
}
return max;
```

To find the min value,

```
 var min = +Infinity;
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] > min) continue;
    if (arr[i] < min) {
        min = arr[i];
 }
}
return min;
```

To find all the occurrences of max values, (alter the comparisons to get all min values)

```
 var max = -Infinity, result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
   if (arr[i] < max) continue;
   if (arr[i] > max) {
      result = [];
      max = arr[i];
    }
   result.push(max);
  }
 return result; // return result.length to return the number of occurrences of max values.
```