# Find the greatest Numerical Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I select all the divs inside another div and find the greatest id attribute?

Consider the following code:

```
<div class="posts">
    <div class="post" data-id="5"></div>
    <div class="post" data-id="3"></div>
    <div class="post" data-id="1"></div>
    <div class="post" data-id="4"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is, find the `div` that's having the greatest `id attribute`

I use the following code to grab the `id attribute`:

```
$('.posts .post').data('id');
```

But that returns the **latest** one, not the **greatest**.

Comment: Which attribute are you looking for? `id` or `data-id`?

Comment: I want `data-id` of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var max = 0;
$('.post').attr("data-id", function(i,v){
   max = +v > max ? +v : max;
});

console.log( max ); // 5
```

---

Another way:

```
var ids = $('.post').map(function(){
   return +this.dataset.id;            // or use jQ: return +$(this).data('id');
});

console.log( Math.max.apply(Math, ids) ); // 5
```

<sup>http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/ used to return a new Array of the desired values.

[How might I find the largest number contained in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array) is used for the rest.</sup>

The unary `+` is used to convert any possible String number to `Number`.
To prevent a `NaN` resulting a mismatch caused by a mistakenly inserted Alpha character you can use:

```
return +this.dataset.id || 0; // Prevent NaN and turn "a" to 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org), this can be done as follows with the [max](http://underscorejs.org/#max) function.

```js
var getIdAttr = function(el){ return el.getAttribute('data-id'); };
var elementIds = _.map($('.post'), getIdAttr);
var maxId = _.max(elementIds);

console.log(maxId); // 5
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div class="posts">
  <div class="post" data-id="3"></div>
  <div class="post" data-id="5"></div>
  <div class="post" data-id="1"></div>
  <div class="post" data-id="4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, cleaner than tracking the value and doing comparisons on your own. Simply push the values to an Array and use Math to determine the max.

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, $(".posts .post").map(function () {
    return $(this).data("id");
}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d0wuxygs/

For reference: [Get max and min value from array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985341/get-max-and-min-value-from-array-in-javascript)