# vue3 find min value from an array

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm trying to get the minimum value from an array in Vue3 but I keep getting an infinity value. Can I please get help?

Below is adding value to the 'ranks' array.

```
const ranks = ref([])
for (let i = 0; i < uni.value.length; i++) {
    ranks.value.push(uni.value[i].rank)
}
```

And here is the finding min code:

```
const min = Math.min(...ranks.value)
console.log(min)  // it returns Infinity
```

this is how my ranks array looks in the console:

[image: ranks array in console]

Comment: You get Infinity if your ranks array is empty. Check if the for loop is actually correctly filling the ranks array.

Comment: the image above is the result of console.log(ranks.value). It shows that there are 3 elements in an array. So I thought adding elements worked fine.

Comment: If you open target in that console.log, what is in it? It might be 3 ‘undefined’ values.

Comment: I edited my image above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get max and min value from array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985341/get-max-and-min-value-from-array-in-javascript)

Comment: You do not need the spread operator (...) then calling `Math.min()`. Or you should calll `Math.min([...ranks.value])`.

Comment: (`Math.min([...ranks.value])`) returned 0!! Although it is not the answer that I want (should be 1) I got something!

Comment: Btw, both (`ranks[0]`) and (`ranks.value[0]`) returned undefined. Maybe this is why I keep getting Infinity value???

Comment: Can you copy the object and share it @JihwanShin...

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I thought earlier. If the ranks are undefined you get the Infinity outcome. It should be in the for loop and the value of the uni object you are using. Try to log what you push into the ranks array.

Answer (score 0):

```
const minValue = (nums) => {
  let min = Infinity; 
  for(let i=0; i< nums.length;i++){
    if(min > nums[i]){
      min = nums[i];
    }
  }
  return min;
};
```

Comment: console.log(minValue(ranks))      should give me the minimum value, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to find the minimum value.

```js
a = [5,4,1,2,3]
let minVal = Infinity
a.forEach(val => minVal = minVal > val ? val : minVal)
console.log('Minimum value is ' + minVal)
```

Comment: Your code works when the array is predefined like above. But, my array is in ref (I'm not sure if this makes any difference), and when I run code "ranks.forEach(val => minVal = minVal > val ? val : minVal)", it throws an error saying "ranks.forEach is not a function".

Comment: You should use ranks.value.forEach since you are using a ref.

Comment: hmm.... it still returns infinity.

Comment: Yes, see my other comment